# what does these python3 output line mean "Input In [1], in <cell line: 18>()" as a result from the following code

Tags: python, class, output, line, semantics

what does these python3 output line mean "Input In [1], in <cell line: 18>()" as a result from the following code

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'
        self.pay = pay

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Schafer', 50000)
emp_2 = Employee('Test', 'Employee', 60000)

Print(emp_1)
Print(emp_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a string representation of your class `Employee`. When you `print` the instance of the class it prints the string representation of your class.

You can check that by `emp_1.__str__`.

You can change your string representation of class like this,

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'
        self.pay = pay

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname()

emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Schafer', 50000)
emp_2 = Employee('Test', 'Employee', 60000)

print(emp_1)
print(emp_2)
```

Output:

```
Corey Schafer
Test Employee
```